# About graphic cards

Tags: intel-graphics, 19.10

I just recently started using Ubuntu and I like it, my question is: I have a msi GTX 970 and I don't understand why Ubuntu considers it as a low end graphic card? anybody have any idea? Cause I'm using Yandex Browser and in the setting, it is written that my graphic card is a low end. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure to have installed the NVIDIA proprietary drivers?

If not, try to execute the following commands:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

to install the drivers

```
sudo reboot
```

to reboot your system and use the new configuration.

...and that's all! :)

PS: for more details, try to take a look [HERE](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-19-10-eoan-ermine-linux)

Comment: I think I have installed it correctly but I will try that command to see what happen. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome! ;)